# How does blowing up the Veridian star change the course of the Nexus ribbon?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-generations

In Star Trek: Generations Soran blows up the Veridian star in order to change the course of the Nexus ribbon. But blowing up a star does not change the **quantity of mass in the general area where the star used to be**, so the total force of gravity would not change (it would still be contained within the orbit of the Veridian system when the ribbon changed course)

The explosion caused a shock wave and maybe even dispersed some of the outer shell but the ribbon's course was changed well before the shock wave reached Veridian III.

**How did blowing up the star change the course of the Nexus?**

Comment: I think it was probably bad science on the part of the writer, but you *could* explain it if Soran's rocket created some kind of wormhole, matter-energy conversion, or phase shift (phenomena familiar to Trek) that sent a significant portion of the mass somewhere else.

Comment: @JohnSensebe I was thinking along those lines. Soran used a trilithium weapon.  We know dilithium is used in regulating warp power, so possibly trilithium uses free energy from the explosion to create some warp or phasing effects.

Comment: Silly of me to use hidden text for something that already appears in the question.

Comment: @Xplodotron - It's hardly a spoiler to begin with. I recall it was in the trailer.

Comment: There is a fallacy about the idea that is does not change the quantity of the mass in the general area.  While this statement is true is is not helpful.  The mass distribution in the general area changes, and this will have an impact on local gravitational forces.  In Relativity terms, the curvature of the region will be adjusted.  Enough to matter for a nexus ribbon? It is fiction, roll with it.

Comment: @Lighhart - But the Shell Theorum?  Also, surely Star Trek is not fiction. In an infinitely large and infinitely long universe, every scene in Star Trek will come to pass, if they haven't already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Caution, treknobabble warning.

The destruction of the Amargosa Star occurs due to the presence of a

> ***quantum implosion.***

that results in the star immediately going dark.

Literally the only way this could occur is if a large portion of the star's mass and energy had gone *elsewhere*. The presence of trilithium (a substance with known subspace properties) could have caused the star to extrude mass into a [separate quantum domain](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Parallels_(episode)), hence why it was a ***quantum*** implosion rather than just a plain old implosion.

Not only did the star *implode*, it simultaneously exploded into another universe. **This would cause a loss of mass and hence the system would exert less gravity on the ribbon.**

Comment: Does it actually say anywhere that it's a quantum implosion?  Or did you just pull that out of your other universe?

Comment: @Xplodotron - **PICARD:** *Report.*
**RIKER:** ***A quantum implosion** has occurred within the Amargosa star. All nuclear fusion is breaking down.*
**PICARD:** *How is that possible?* / http://www.chakoteya.net/movies/movie7.html

Answer (score 4):

I think the key is the destruction of the star spreads it's matter out all over the star system. The gravitational forces are no longer at the point of the star.

In the dialogue between Data and Picard:

> PICARD: It's close to Veridian Three ...but not close enough. ...Data, what would happen to the ribbon's course if Soran destroyed the Veridian star itself? ...That's where he's going.
>   DATA: **It should be noted, sir, that the collapse of the Veridian star would produce a shock wave similar to the one we observed at Amargosa.**
>   PICARD: **Destroying all the planets in this system.** - [Generations transcript](http://www.chakoteya.net/movies/movie7.html)

[image]

> The Enterprise moves to avoid the shock wave from the destruction of the Amargosa star.

Slightly before in the above conversation.

> DATA: The destruction of the Amargosa star has altered the gravitational forces throughout this sector. As a result any ship passing through this region would have to make a minor course correction.

He says it is a minor course change, so it wasn't like everything in the universe was affected by this redistribution of gravity, but it was enough that things within the system were affected (ships need to change course, planets were destroyed, etc).

Sounds to me like the gravity would be equalized across the system, instead of being focused at the center, where it could affect the path of the Nexus.

For reference I've added the shots of the Nexus' course being changed by the absence of the Veridian star.

[image]

[image]

*All pictures sourced from http://movie-screencaps.com/star-trek-generations-1994/29/*

Comment: Damn fine answer.  But Newton proved the validity of the Shell Theorem to simplify the calcluations: the gravity of any mass symmetrically distributed in a sphere can be calculated (from outside that sphere) as if all the mass was concentrated in a point.  So, assuming the star blew up in a spherical manner (yes, an assumption) the spreading out of the star's mass would not change the effect of that mass' gravity.  I think.

Comment: Actually, if the Nexus were passing close enough, it would be within the shell after the star was destroyed.

Comment: Huh? We know the ribbon was not within the shell because it passed Veridian III before the shockwave reached it.

Comment: @Xplodotron the timing of the star's death and when the Nexus passes by the planet is the gaping hole in this explanation, unless Soran's starkiller torpedo *destroys* matter.

Comment: @JackBNimble I always took it as the matter was just converted into energy, hence why you see that large energy pulse that comes from the star and evaporates the planets.

Comment: @Xplodotron  Your response has an implicit assumption that Newtonian physics apply here.  But I think the relativistic changes in the curvature of space need to be considered as well, and those changes are are not governed by the shell theorem as best I can tell.